# Can a (C/C++) array initialization reference itself?

Tags: c++

I was wondering about an initialization of the following form:

```
int  array[] = {
v - 1,
array[0] + 1
} ;
```

In the initialization of the second element, the value of the first is used, but the entire array is not yet initialized.  This happens to compile with g++, but I was unsure whether this is actually portable and a well defined construct?

Comment: @ptomato: Because not all compilers are standard compliant - especially in weird edge-cases like this.

Comment: @ptomato In C and C++, "try it" is generally problematic. A lots of compiler have incompatible and non-standard extensions, and a lot of undefined behaviour may seem consistent in a few tests on a single platform.

Comment: I removed the C tag since your question mentions that you are compiling with g++

Comment: You'd probably be better off using a for-loop to initialize the array.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan But maybe he wants C and C++ answer if they behave differently?

Comment: The real code can't use a for loop and has a much more complex sequence of initialization values (many of which reference the earlier array offset positions).

Comment: @ChristianRau But we generally ask one question at a time here

Comment: constraining this question to C++ is fine (but the answer I'm interested in not be compiler specific since the code in question is built with compilers including g++, xlC, sunstudio 12.1, hpux aCC, intel, microsoft visual studio, and perhaps a few others that I am forgetting).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Ok, I see. Since he didn't clearly say he wants a C and a C++ answer probably means he wants a C/C++ answer, in which case cleaning up tags was a good idea, anyway.

Comment: @ChristianRau There's no such thing as C/C++!!

Comment: This makes me thing strongly of designated initializers in C: `static int array[] = { [0] = 5, [2] = 7 };`, it did not seem to make it in C++11 though...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's why I reasoned it was indeed a good idea from you to clean up the tags, so that we don't encourage *C/C++* questions and answers. I hope those two exclamation marks are not directed to me, as I'm the last one to use the term *C/C++* in a serious context (maybe I should've used italics in my previous comment, too, but I didn't want it to sound even more sarcastic).

Comment: @ChristianRau Sorry, that was an involuntary reflex reaction to seeing *C/C++*   ;-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See 3.3.2 Point of declaration:

> The point of declaration for a name is immediately after its complete declarator (Clause 8) and before its
> initializer (if any), except as noted below. [ Example:

```
int x = 12;
{ int x = x; }
```

> Here the second x is initialized with its own (indeterminate) value. —end example ]

So you are referring to the array correctly, its name is known after the `=`.

Then, 8.5.1 Aggregates:

> An aggregate is an array or a class [...]
>
> 17: The full-expressions in an initializer-clause are evaluated in the order in which they appear.

However, I see no reference to when the evaluated values are actually written into the array, so I wouldn't rely on this and would even go so far to declare your code as not well defined.

Answer (score 13):

As far as I can see, this is *not* well defined. The standard (C++11, 8.5.1/17) specifies that "The *full-expressions* in an *initializer-clause* are evaluated in the order in which they appear", but I can't see anything that requires each aggregate element to be initialised from the result of its *initializer-clause* before the next is evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

> Can a (C/C++) array initialization reference itself?

This is also valid C code.

C has some correspondent paragraph (emphasis mine).

> (C99, 6.2.1p7) "Structure, union, and enumeration tags have scope that begins just after the appearance of the tag in a type specifier that declares the tag. Each enumeration constant has scope that begins just after the appearance of its defining enumerator in an enumerator list. **Any other identifier has scope that begins just after the completion of its declarator.**"

Answer (score 1):

I think this is handled by http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1343 . Initially my report was only about non-class initializers for namespace scope objects (see [When exactly is an initializer temporary destroyed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760866/when-exactly-is-an-initializer-temporary-destroyed)), but the problem exists for aggregate elements just aswell if they are non-class. And as the additional recent note explains, even seems to exist for the entire aggregate initialization aswell, even if it is a class object, because then no constructor call happens that would enlargen the full-expression of the initializer.

If instead of `int` you would have used a class, and the initialization would be a constructor call, then that constructor call would be part of the same full expression that encloses the aggregate-ininitializer element, so that here the order would be OK and your code would be well-defined.